# ValueError: Cannot cast DatetimeIndex to dtype datetime64[us]

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas

I'm trying to create a PostgreSQL table of 30-minute data for the S&P 500 ETF
(spy30new, for testing freshly inserted data) from a table of several stocks with 15-minute data (all15). all15 has an index on 'dt' (timestamp) and 'instr' (stock symbol). I would like spy30new to have an index on 'dt'.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timedelta
from dateutil import parser
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# Query all15
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:passwd@localhost:5432/stocks')
new15Df = (pd.read_sql_query("SELECT dt, o, h, l, c, v FROM all15 WHERE (instr = 'SPY') AND (date(dt) BETWEEN '2016-06-27' AND '2016-07-15');", engine)).sort_values('dt')
# Correct for Time Zone.
new15Df['dt'] = (new15Df['dt'].copy()).apply(lambda d: d + timedelta(hours=-4))

# spy0030Df contains the 15-minute data at 00 & 30 minute time points
# spy1545Df contains the 15-minute data at 15 & 45 minute time points
spy0030Df = (new15Df[new15Df['dt'].apply(lambda d: d.minute % 30) == 0]).reset_index(drop=True)
spy1545Df = (new15Df[new15Df['dt'].apply(lambda d: d.minute % 30) == 15]).reset_index(drop=True)

high = pd.concat([spy1545Df['h'], spy0030Df['h']], axis=1).max(axis=1)
low = pd.concat([spy1545Df['l'], spy0030Df['l']], axis=1).min(axis=1)
volume = spy1545Df['v'] + spy0030Df['v']

# spy30Df assembled and pushed to PostgreSQL as table spy30new
spy30Df = pd.concat([spy0030Df['dt'], spy1545Df['o'], high, low, spy0030Df['c'], volume], ignore_index = True, axis=1)
spy30Df.columns = ['d', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v']
spy30Df.set_index(['dt'], inplace=True)
spy30Df.to_sql('spy30new', engine, if_exists='append', index_label='dt')
```

This gives the error "ValueError: Cannot cast DatetimeIndex to dtype datetime64[us]"
What I've tried so far (I have successfully pushed CSV files to PG using pandas. But here the source is a PG database):

1. **Not placing an index on `'dt'`**

   ```
   spy30Df.set_index(['dt'], inplace=True)  # Remove this line
   spy30Df.to_sql('spy30new', engine, if_exists='append')  # Delete the index_label option
   ```
2. **Converting 'dt' from type pandas.tslib.Timestamp to datetime.datetime using `to_pydatetime()`** (in case psycopg2 can work with python dt, but not pandas Timestamp)

   ```
   u = (spy0030Df['dt']).tolist()
   timesAsPyDt = np.asarray(map((lambda d: d.to_pydatetime()), u))
   spy30Df = pd.concat([spy1545Df['o'], high, low, spy0030Df['c'], volume], ignore_index = True, axis=1)
   newArray = np.c_[timesAsPyDt, spy30Df.values]
   colNames = ['dt', 'o', 'h', 'l', 'c', 'v']
   newDf = pd.DataFrame(newArray, columns=colNames)
   newDf.set_index(['dt'], inplace=True)
   newDf.to_sql('spy30new', engine, if_exists='append', index_label='dt')
   ```
3. **Using `datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`**

   ```
   timesAsDt = (spy0030Df['dt']).apply(lambda d: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(d.tolist()/1e9))
   ```
4. **Using `pd.to_datetime()`**

   ```
   timesAsDt = pd.to_datetime(spy0030Df['dt'])
   ```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using pd.to_datetime() on each element worked. Option 4, which doesn't work, applies pd.to_datetime() to the entire series. Perhaps the Postgres driver understands python datetime, but not datetime64 in pandas & numpy. Option 4 produced the correct output, but I got ValueError (see title) when sending the DF to Postgres

```
timesAsPyDt = (spy0030Df['dt']).apply(lambda d: pd.to_datetime(str(d)))
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and applying `pd.to_datetime()` on each element worked as well. But it is orders of magnitude slower than running `pd.to_datetime()` on the entire series. For a dataframe with over a 1 million rows:

```
(df['Time']).apply(lambda d: pd.to_datetime(str(d)))
```

takes approximately 70 seconds

and

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
```

takes approximately 0.01 seconds

The actual problem is that timezone information is being included. To remove it:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
t = t.tz_localize(None)
```

This should be much faster!

Answer (score 5):

Actually, this was my data frame.

```
                              Biomass  Fossil Brown coal/Lignite  Fossil Coal-derived gas  Fossil Gas  Fossil Hard coal  Fossil Oil  Geothermal  Hydro Pumped Storage  Hydro Run-of-river and poundage  Hydro Water Reservoir  Nuclear   Other  Other renewable    Solar  Waste  Wind Offshore  Wind Onshore
2018-02-02 00:00:00+01:00   4835.0                    16275.0                    446.0      1013.0            4071.0       155.0         5.0                   7.0                           1906.0                   35.0   8924.0  3643.0            142.0      0.0  595.0         2517.0       19999.0
2018-02-02 00:15:00+01:00   4834.0                    16272.0                    446.0      1010.0            3983.0       155.0         5.0                   7.0                           1908.0                   71.0   8996.0  3878.0            142.0      0.0  594.0         2364.0       19854.0
2018-02-02 00:30:00+01:00   4828.0                    16393.0                    446.0      1019.0            4015.0       155.0         5.0
```

I was trying to insert into SQL database but getting the same error as in the above question. What i have done is, convert the index of the data frame to the column with a label 'index'.

```
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

Rename the column name 'index' to 'DateTime' by using this code.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'index': 'DateTime'})
```

Change the datatype to the 'datetime64'.

```
df['DateTime'] = df['DateTime'].astype('datetime64')
```

Store it in the sql database using these code.

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:Password@localhost/generation_data', echo=True)
df.to_sql(con=engine, name='test', if_exists='replace')
```